# Qt difference between class pointers

Tags: c++, qt

I have just started learning Qt and there are some things I don't understand.
So I made widget app by creator and the framework created header and cpp file for
MainWindow.

> Header file

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QLayout>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:


private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QLayout *aLayout;
    QLayout *bLayout;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

> Cpp file

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->...
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

My question is what's the difference between objects pointed by `ui` made by constructor and `this` used in the same constructor. Also, why can't I acces MainWindow members by `ui` pointer?

Comment: `ui` points to `Ui::MainWindow` and `this` points to `MainWindow` - these are different classes (the same name, but different namespaces) and different objects. Therefore you cannot access members of one class through the pointer to another class object.

Comment: so `Ui::MainWindow` is not the `MainWindow` class from header file?

Comment: It is automatically named like that in order to indicate, that this UI belongs to this class. But they are different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your member 'ui' has type Ui :: MainWindow - it's a class, which was generated from your form. That class is generated by UIC. http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/uic.html

'this' pointer - is a pointer to the current class, in your case it has type MainWindow.

Ui :: MainWindow and MainWindow are not the same. If you want to access to a button that was created by Qt Designer - use 'ui' member, not 'this' pointer.

Probably this link would help you http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/designer-using-a-ui-file.html

Answer (score 1):

When you create a widget in Qt, there is some magic (if everything is set up nice, which would be the case when using a template). Qt will generate the `ui` class from the .ui file you edited. This class contains all the widgets you added with the designer. ([see the answer of Arman for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52514240/1228771))

The `this` pointer is a C++ basic concept, which is the class you are working in. You could actually write 'this->ui->setupUi(this)` for example.

If you cannot access the widgets you created through `ui`, it might mean you first have to compile so that Qt can do it's magic. If you already did, it might mean something has gone bogus, which I highly doubt

Comment: This answer is best suited for hogwarts.stackexchange.com. <-- This is a joke, obviously.

Comment: :) all jokes aside, could you please elaborate on what and how the magic happens, as it could be useful for the readers.